# How to parse JSON on Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am working on reading database and parse that into listview on Android. Basically I have setup a web service using PHP and MySQL and now am trying to parse data into android list view. I am getting the following errors:

```
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846): Process: com.example.test, PID: 846
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured     while executing doInBackground()
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at     android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.example.test.Menu.updateJSONdata(Menu.java:107)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.example.test.Menu$LoadComments.doInBackground(Menu.java:189)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.example.test.Menu$LoadComments.doInBackground(Menu.java:1)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-31 14:24:55.570: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

**The Main class is:**

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
  import android.widget.ListAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{ 

//Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// php read comments script


// testing on Emulator:
private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1337/webservice/lib.php";


// JSON IDS:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
private static final String TAG_CALLING = "calling";    //calling
private static final String TAG_ACCESSION = "accession";    //accession
private static final String TAG_AUTHOR = "author";  //author


// An array of all of our comments
private JSONArray mComments = null;
// manages all of our comments in a list.
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // note that use read_comments.xml instead of our single_post.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    // loading the comments via AsyncTask
    new LoadComments().execute();
}

/*public void addComment(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ReadComments.this, AddComment.class);
    startActivity(i);
} */

/**
 * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
 */
public void updateJSONdata() {


    mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);


    try {


        mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

        // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
        for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

            // gets the content of each tag
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String author = c.getString(TAG_AUTHOR);
            String accession = c.getString(TAG_ACCESSION);
            String calling = c.getString(TAG_CALLING);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put(TAG_AUTHOR, author);
            map.put(TAG_ACCESSION, accession);
            map.put(TAG_CALLING, calling);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            mCommentList.add(map);


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
 */
private void updateList() {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Menu.this, mCommentList,
            R.layout.onepost, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_AUTHOR,
                    TAG_ACCESSION, TAG_CALLING }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.author,
                    R.id.accession, R.id.calling });


    setListAdapter(adapter);


    ListView lv = getListView();    
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


        }
    });
}

public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Menu.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Comments...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        updateJSONdata();
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        updateList();
    }
     }


   }
```

Comment: It's probably worth un-tagging this from PHP: Assuming your PHP is generating valid JSON, your problem lies in your Android code.

Comment: I expect `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` is the issue, and the place that triggers this is clearly in the stack trace. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done 2 class to get http requests results. Very easy to use.

BasicHttpRequest.java

```
public class BasicHttpRequest
{
    private JSONObject      _result         = null;
    private int             _err            = -1;
    private String          _errMessage     = null;
    private HttpRequestBase _request        = null;
    private String          _requestError   = null;
    private UrlBuilder      _urlBuilder     = null;

    public BasicHttpRequest(RequestType requestType, UrlBuilder urlBuilder)
    {
        this._urlBuilder = urlBuilder;
        if (requestType.equals(RequestType.POST))
            this.createPostRequest();
        if (requestType.equals(RequestType.GET))
            this.createGetRequest();
    }

    private void createPostRequest()
    {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(this._urlBuilder.getUrlBase());

        try
        {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this._urlBuilder.getArrayList()));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        this._request = post;
    }

    private void createGetRequest()
    {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(this._urlBuilder.getUrl());

        this._request = get;
    }

    /**
     * This function executes the request passed by the constructor.
     * @return Returns false if an error occurred, true otherwise. For more informations about the error, use getRequestError.
     */
    public boolean executeRequest()
    {
        InputStream iStream = null;
        String result = "";

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(this._request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            iStream = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ReqError", "[Error in HTTP Connection] : " + e.toString());
            this._requestError = ErrorMessage.CONNECTION_ERROR;
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ConversionError", "[Error while converting result] : " + e.toString());
            this._requestError = ErrorMessage.DATA_ERROR;
            return false;
        }

        JSONObject jObject;
        try
        {
            jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            this._err = jObject.getInt("err");
            this._errMessage = jObject.getString("errMessage");

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("JSONError", "[Error parsing data] : " + e.toString());
            this._requestError = ErrorMessage.DATA_ERROR;
            return false;
        }
        this._result = jObject;
        return true;
    }

    public String getValueForKey(String key)
    {
        String value = null;

        if (this._result == null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            value = this._result.getString(key);
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        if (value.equals("null"))
            return null;
        return value;
    }

    public boolean hasError()
    {
        if (this._err == 0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getErrMessage()
    {
        return this._errMessage;
    }

    public JSONObject getResult()
    {
        return this._result;
    }

    /**
     * This function gives you the reason of the request error.
     * @return Returns an error message if an error occurred during the request execution, null otherwise.
     */
    public String getRequestError()
    {
        return this._requestError;
    }
}
```

UrlBuilder.java

```
public class UrlBuilder
{
    private String _urlBase;
    private HashMap<String, String> _urlArgs;

    public UrlBuilder(String urlBase)
    {
        this._urlArgs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this._urlBase = urlBase;
    }

    public UrlBuilder addArgument(String name, String value)
    {
        this._urlArgs.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    public void removeArgument(String name)
    {
        this._urlArgs.remove(name);
    }

    public boolean argumentExists(String name)
    {
        return this._urlArgs.containsKey(name);
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        int i = 0;
        String url = this._urlBase;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : this._urlArgs.entrySet())
        {
            url += (i == 0 ? "?" : "&");
            try
            {
                url += URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                Log.e("UrlEncoder", "Error while trying to encode URL");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
        return url;
    }

    public String getUrlBase()
    {
        return this._urlBase;
    }

    public List<NameValuePair> getArrayList()
    {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : this._urlArgs.entrySet())
        {
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return nameValuePairs;
    }
}
```

Just instantiate an UrlBuilder with your server URL base like "http://api.yoursite.fr/page" and add your arguments with the method addArgument. Then, instantiate a BasicHttpRequest object with the previous UrlBuilder instance and the request type (it's just an Enum with POST and GET). Finally, get the results with the BasicHttpRequest method getValueForKey.

Ask me if you have any question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have implemented this already, but thank you so much for looking at it again and answering :)